# iOS check user access token validity when app launches: best practice

Tags: ios, authentication, login-control, autologin, launching-application

I am currently developing an app which does have a user system. After user logins to the app, I will store user access token from the server and next time the app launches, the user will be auto logged in(or the login screen will be displayed if user is not logged, so the rootViewController will be set in applicaion didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).

So my question is what is the best practice for this? Currently what I have in mind is to set the root view controller to be some new controller(with in a spinner to indicate progress), and after the auto login(checking with server if the access token stored is still valid, if not valid, can be refreshed or not and stuff), I will manually set the rootViewController to be the correct one.

Someone also suggested me to hold the launch screen until the response from server is received.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Its may depends on the app security level. ie. Once the home page have no more secure details to display you don't have to hold at launch screen. but If you are developing a high secured app, Its must wait at launch screen until the responds is come from server for token check.